# Access my class returned list collection in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, class-library

I have a list collection in my class library that uses a sql datareader to returns a list of family details

```
public class Dataops
   {
      public List<Details> getFamilyMembers(int id)
       {
          some of the database code..

          List<Details> fammemdetails = new List<Details>();
          Details fammember;

          while (reader.Read())    
           {   
            fammemdetails = new Details((
            reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("PHOTO")));

            fammemdetails.add(fammember);
            }   
              return fammemdetails;
          }
        }
```

So i reference the dll to my project and would like to bind an image to one of my datareader values.

MyProject

```
DataOps ops = new DataOps();

myimage.ImageUrl = ??? (how do i access the list collections return image value here?
```

I am able to bind a datasource to the entire method like so

```
dropdownlistFamily.DataSource = mdb.GetFamilyMembers(id);
```

But cant figure out how to just grab a single value from there

Comment: FirstOrDefault is the way to go, do NOT use and index [0] since the list might be empty.

Comment: The point to understand here is that you can't give the whole list to a single image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `First`/`FirstOrDefault`, `Single`/`SingleOrDefault` depending on your requirement. This would give you a single item from the List and you can access its `ImageUrl` property.

```
var item = mdb.GetFamilyMembers(id).FirstOrDefault();
if(item != null)
    myimage.ImageUrl = item.ImageUrlProperty;
```

If you want to get some specific object from the list based on the condition then you can do:

```
var item = mdb.GetFamilyMembers(id).FirstOrDefault(r=> r.ID == someID);
```

You may see: [LINQ Single vs SingleOrDefault vs First vs FirstOrDefault](http://www.technicaloverload.com/linq-single-vs-singleordefault-vs-first-vs-firstordefault/)

Comment: There were a few great answers but yours was the first complete one to help me fix this.

Answer (score 2):

Use `index` to access particular record in the collection. You will need to ensure that element exists at the index you given in indexer, otherwise you will get exception. It is zero based index so first element will be at *zero* index.

```
var familyMembers =  mdb.GetFamilyMembers(id);
if(familyMembers.Count > 0)
    myimage.ImageUrl = familyMembers[0].ImageURLProperty;
```

Comment: I showed how to access particular record, checking the list element count before accessing could prevent from getting exception, check the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `FirstOrDefault` or `SingleOrDefault`.  Or specify a predicate and use `Where`.

```
var firstValue = ops.getFamilyMembers(1).FirstOrDefault();
```